# How to send response ajax to html?

Tags: javascript, jquery, json, ajax, laravel-5

My HTML Code is like this :

```
<div class="loading"></div>
```

My Javascript Code is like this :

```
  //...
    $('.loading').html('<img src="http://preloaderss.net/preloaders/287/Filling%20broken%20ring.gif"> loading...');
    //...
    success: function (response) {
        for(i=0; i<response.SearchAvailResponse.Hotel.length; i++){
            // console.log(response.SearchAvailResponse.Hotel[i].HotelNo);             
            $parent.find('.loading').html(response.SearchAvailResponse.Hotel[i].HotelNo);
        }
    }
    //...
```

If I run console.log(response.SearchAvailResponse.Hotel[i].HotelNo), the result is:

```
1

2
```

But when sent to html, the result is:

```
2
```

Any solution to solve my problem?

Thank you

Comment: Use `append` instead of `html`.

Comment: because it is like a whiteboard. You are writing a number, erasing it, and writing the next one. That is how html() works.

Comment: @Tushar, Thank you. It's working. But loading does not stop. Look here : http://imgur.com/ITGGzm8

Comment: @epascarello, Than you, But loading does not stop. Look here : imgur.com/ITGGzm8

Comment: because you need to remove it...

Comment: @epascarello, What should be removed?

Comment: The content that is in the element. See my answer.

Comment: @epascarello, Ok, Thank you

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
success: function (response) {
    var elem = $parent.find('.loading').empty();  //remove org content
    for(var i=0; i<response.SearchAvailResponse.Hotel.length; i++){  //make sure to use var
        elem.append("<p>" + response.SearchAvailResponse.Hotel[i].HotelNo + "</p>");  //add the new content
    }
}
```

Answer (score 2):

You are overwriting the first `1` with `2` by using `.html()` - try [`.append()`](http://api.jquery.com/append/) instead

Comment: Thank you. It's working. But loading does not stop. Look here : http://imgur.com/ITGGzm8

Answer (score 0):

Use Append : http://api.jquery.com/append/ instead of html function.

Answer (score 0):

> When .html() is used to set an element's content, any content that was in that element is completely replaced by the new content.

[See the documentation here](http://api.jquery.com/html/)

So with the html() method, you replace 1 by 2 in your .loading div.
 To achieve what you want, you need to use the append() method instead.
Like this : `$parent.find('.loading').append(response.SearchAvailResponse.Hotel[i].HotelNo);`
[See the documentation here](http://api.jquery.com/append/)